# Can't find a logical formulation to this problem

Tags: logic, puzzle

> In this problem are only truth tellers and liars. When meeting two
>   people, A and B, you ask A: "Is any of you a truth teller?", to which
>   A replies: "If B is a liars, then i'm a liar" What are A and B?

**What I got so far is:**

If A is telling the truth, then the statement must be true when B is telling the truth, and false when B is lying. If A is lying, then the statement must be true when B is telling the truth, and false when he is lying.

I can't seem to find a way to logically formulate this, and I'm thinking this might be because I'm missing something. Have I got it right?

Comment: I approached such problems (from classical Smullyan books) by reformulating them as $xor(l, p)$ and solving usinig logic; $l$ means "speaker of a sentence $p$ is a liar" and $p$ is of course sentence which was uttered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we say that $L(x)$ means "$x$ is a liar", then $A$ said the following statement:
$$L(B)\implies L(A)$$

First, examine the two cases:

1. If $A$ is a liar, then the statement is false, meaning that the statement $(\neg L(B)\implies L(A))$ is true. This is equivalent to $\neg(\neg L(B) \vee L(A))$ which is $L(B)\wedge \neg L(A)$, so if $A$ is a liar, then $B$ is a liar and $A$ is not a liar, a contradiction.
2. If $A$ is not a liar, then $L(B)\implies L(A)$ is true. If $B$ would be a liar, then $A$ would be a liar which would be a contradiction, so $B$ is not a liar. If $B$ is not a liar, then nothing can be said of $A$, so there is no contradiction.

Conclusion: neither of them is a liar.

Comment: I'm not sure i follow you completely. You are looking at the truth table for implication right? If you say in 1. that "If A is a liar, then the statement is false", but what if they are both lying, then the statement would be true. Or are you ruling that out by saying that they can't both be liars, because A would then be telling the truth?

Comment: @Attaque If $A$ is a liar, then the statement $L(B)\implies L(A)$ is false. This is because $A$ always says false statements if $A$ is a liar. There is no "both lying" here.

Comment: Ah yes of course. Makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can deduce from "If A is telling the truth, then the statement must be true when B is telling the truth, and false when B is lying" that if A is a truth teller then B is a truth teller.

You can deduce a contradiction from "If A is lying, then the statement must be true when B is telling the truth, and false when he is lying" but I would prefer to consider all eight possibilities:

```
 A     B   Statement  Comment 
TT    TT   True       Consistent: B is not a liar so A need not be a liar
TT    TT   False      Inconsistent: A is a truth teller so cannot state false
TT    Liar True       Inconsistent: B is a liar so A must be a liar
TT    Liar False      Inconsistent: A is a truth teller so cannot state false
Liar  TT   True       Inconsistent: A is a liar so cannot state true
Liar  TT   False      Inconsistent: Statement is vacuously true as B not liar
Liar  Liar True       Inconsistent: A is a liar so cannot state true
Liar  Liar False      Inconsistent: Statement is true as A and B are both liars
```

Comment: Thank you Henry, although I'm a bit confused on how to actually take on a problem like this.. So my way of solving this would be to start off with the truth table for B indicates A, and then seeing that for A:T and B:F, A would not keep the promise and so the statement will be false. Then for A:F and B:F There is the contradiction of A, which will make the statement false. This would resolve in a truth table saying: A:T B:T True, A:T B:F False, A:F B:T False, A:F B:F False. Is this a right way to go?

Comment: Your method could work if you did not lose track of where you were.  I am not sure you have managed that